# show and hide collapsible with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't show and hide collapsible bootstrap.

How to do this with JavaScript since the bootstrap is not working due to loading more libraries?

[image]

```js
$('element').click(function() {
  if (open) {
    //close
  } else {
    //open
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: if bootstrap is not working due to loading more libraries then why bother and use bootstrap html classes?

Comment: `click(functino()` ≠ `click(function()`

Comment: Why don't use bootstrap javascript (37kb)? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which switches a hidden element to visible and a visible element to hidden.